# Trying to add items to localStorage but stuck in an endless refresh hell

Tags: javascript, oop

So I was following a video of an online course just fine when a "books.push is not a function error" appeared on the console, and I just can't get rid of it! I even downloaded the author's code and it's there as well. Whenever I try to add a book the page just reloads and nothing happens, it won't even be added to LS. 
Btw other methods are empty because I stopped after this silent nightmarish bug came to life.

Update: to make things even more weird, on CodePen it works just fine, the data is added to localStorage, but when running it on live server @ Firefox the bug is there anyways. Is this a browser bug then?

Please check the link below

https://codepen.io/mateusmlo/pen/JZKbar

```
    static addBook(book){
    const books = Store.getBooks();

    books.push(book);

    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
}

static removeBook(){

}
```

Update 2: ok so it really turned out to be a browser issue, sorry I didn't say it was Firefox DEVELOPER Edition, on normal Firefox it didn't happen. But everyone gave me some precious insights that I will indeed take notes in the future. Thank you guys!

Comment: Add a break point in the debugger (recommend using chrome's over ff's) to see the value of `books` is right before you try to push to it. And it is highly unlikely to be a browser bug. My guess is that `books` got set in `localStorage` to some non-null value at some point that isn't an array, so now the conditional check thinks everything's cool then your code blows up (which is a good sign it wasn't robust enough anyway).

Comment: Empty your browser caches to see if that would help.

Comment: Does not look like browser issue, as you said CodePen works fine, even on firefox. Also you need to follow @JaredSmith instructions to see if you have anything in Local Storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get that in a book you don't want to introduce too many things at once and the author had to take some shortcuts, but if your code expects something to be an array then it should in fact check (or have a static typechecker check) that it is in fact an array. The `getBooks` method should be rewritten as follows:

```
static getBooks () {
  const stored = localStorage.getItem('books');
  let books = []; // default to empty array

  // need the try-catch here because the parse can fail
  try {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(stored);
    if (Array.isArray(parsed)) { // check that it's an array
      books = parsed;
    } // else leave books as default
  } catch (e) {
    // no-op, leave books as default
  }

  return books;
}
```

Now the code will

1. Always return an array and nothing else
2. Always succeed. There's a very strong convention that a getter should never throw, and the parse can fail in the original method.

If you are in to pointless micro-optimizations, you can also add an early return to skip the `try/catch` if `stored` is `null` or `undefined`.

The original is almost certainly failing because something like this happened:

```
localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify({})); // NOTE: {} not []
```

Now when it's retrieved:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('books') === null) { // this will be false, because it's not null
```

Then later

```
books.push(whatever); // oops! books is {} not []! No push method for you
```

Which would explain why refreshing doesn't fix it, and why the same code runs just fine on a different page (e.g. the codepen). If you opened the console on that page and typed `localStorage.setItem('books', '[]')` you might suddenly see your problem vanish.